# Where is the default log location for SharePoint/MOSS?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I found the answer after digging and thought I'd store it here.
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS

Comment: Or, in more modern versions, 14 (instead of 12); it might be even higher now, I don't know - I'm using Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

SharePoint uses a lot of different logging mechanisms. Most importantly you can configure the location of the logs through Central Admin. To give you an understanding of the logs involved, here is a quote from http://raiumair.wordpress.com/2007/06/19/quick-a-to-z-of-sharepoint-logs/

> All file based logs can be read by
>   text editors and can be parsed by
>   using popular log parsing tools (Log
>   Parser 2.2 from Microsoft or Funnel
>   Web). It will also be a good idea to
>   read the IIS Logs which are generally
>   saved at  (System
>   Drive):\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles
>
> a)      Diagnostics Logs
>
> ·         Event Throttling Logs –
>   These end up going to the Windows
>   Event Log and can be viewed in the
>   Event Viewer. They show Errors and
>   Warnings.
>
> ·         Trace Logs – These show
>   detailed line by line tracing
>   infomration emitted during a web
>   request or service execution. They end
>   up being stored at a known location on
>   the front-end server. Default
>   Location: (System Drive):\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS\
>
> b)      Audit Logs - They end up in
>   the associated Content Database tables
>   and can be viewed at Site Collection
>   Level as well as Site Level using the
>   web browser. WSS 3.0 and MOSS 2007 use
>   different pages to show Audit Log
>   Reports.
>
> c)       Usage Logs – They get stored
>   locally on the front-end servers and
>   get processed both locally and at farm
>   level via SSP (this is based on the
>   setup as I understand the results from
>   the local processing are merged by
>   SSP) and can be viewed at both the
>   Site Level and Site Collection Level.
>   Default Location: (System
>   Drive):\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\Logs
>
> d)      Search\Query Logs – These are
>   saved in the associated SSP database
>   but can be viewed at SSP level via the
>   Web Browser and in MOSS at Site
>   Collection Level by going to the
>   settings page.
>
> e)      Information Management Logs –
>   Stored in the associated Content
>   Database and can be can be viewed at
>   the Site Collection Level.
>
> f)       Content and Structure Logs –
>   This option is only available after
>   one enables the publication feature.
>   This store is saved in the Content
>   Database associated with the Site
>   Collection and can be viewed at Site
>   Collection level by going to the
>   settings page.

Answer (score 11):

By default they are stored here:
**%commonprogramfiles%/Microsoft Shared/web server extensions/12/Logs**

Using **%commonprogramfiles%** make it works in non-english systems.

Comment: On SP 2012 this is %commonprogramfiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\Logs

Comment: Yes, this is correct for SharePoint 2010, but this question was in 09 :)

Answer (score 7):

In SharePoint 2013 they are stored in:

`%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\LOGS`

Answer (score 6):

In Sharepoint Server 2010 they are stored here:

```
"c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\LOGS"
```

To view them you can use ULS Viewer by Microsoft (unsupported). http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

For Sharepoint 2007

**`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS`**

Comment: Should specify that this is for SP 2007.

Answer (score 0):

**For SharePoint 2016**

```
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Logs
```

**For SharePoint 2013**

```
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Logs
```

**For SharePoint 2010**

```
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs
```

**For SharePoint 2007**

```
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Logs
```

> **Note:** The sharePoint Trace log path can be changed by opening  Central
> Administration > Monitoring > Reporting > Configure Diagnostic Logs
>
> For more details check [SHAREPOINT ULS VIEWER](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/15/uls-viewer-tool/)