# feature deactivation through command line not firing the SPFeature event reciever

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, stsadm, event-receiver, sharepoint-feature

I am deactivating a feature through stsadm tool. I have an event reciever enabled for this action. If i deactivate the feature manually from the site the event is getting triggered but not when running stsadm command.

Please help...

Here is the code Sylvain:

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        Logging.Log(_componentName, "The document library feature has deactivated successfully.");
    }
```

Comment: Does it execute when you use powershell?

Comment: Yes i tried with powershell, result same...

Answer (score 2):

In the code of your event receiver, do you use SPContext.Current (or other Web-Context objects)... ? 
If so, your code works on the site, but not out of web-context (like stsadm or command line) because SPContext.Current is null.

Check this point, but there's a good probability that's the problem.

Comment: WE tried with just a file logging function, didnot use any SP function

Answer (score 0):

As Sylvain Reverdy pointing out it is more likley your feature receiver to fail than not beeing called. Check out SharePoint logs - all feature activation/deactivation/installation steps are traced there (Location - c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\LOGS, see [Where is the default log location for SharePoint/MOSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525197/where-is-the-default-log-location-for-sharepoint-moss)).

Make sure you are not using "-force" option of StsAdm command - it makes stsadm to ignore failures during deactivation.

Comment: I am using the force command...stsadm -o deactivatefeature -filename folder/feature.xml -url http://server-name/ -force... i will try to trace the error